# Application pool Identity

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8.5

How can we get the identity of application pool on which account it is running using PowerShell. Please help. I am facing few connectivity issues with the identity which application pool is using.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, managing IIS via PowerShell requires Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

while IIS 10 introduces a new set of cmdlets,

http://blogs.iis.net/bariscaglar/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets-new-feature-in-windows-10-server-2016

Answer (score 0):

The identity of an application pool is like so:

IIS AppPool\apppoolName

So if your website is www.mysite.com, and your app pool name is the same as the site name, then the identity of the app pool will be "IIS AppPool\www.mysite.com"